# What was the official story of the Harkonnen invasion of Dune?

Tags: dune

During the first book, the house Atreides gains control over Arrakis from the Harkonnen by the emperor's command. Afterwards, the Harkonnen take Arrakis back with the help of the Sardukar.

What was the official story? Did the Landsraad know that the Harkonnen attacked Dune and thus officially opposed the emperor's command? If so, what was their justification for it?

Comment: In the first book, House Atreides is given control of Arrakis by the Emperor. Does that difference matter?

The Harkonnen do not take; they merely try to take Arrakis back with the help of the Sardaukar. Does that difference matter?

How do you imagine the Landsraad could not know that the Harkonnen attacked Dune, opposing the Emperor?

In any case, what justification could be needed but greed?

Whether that's purely Harkonnen greed, or the Emperor has been bribed, changes what?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The two houses are ancient enemies. The Baron has recently offered to meet with the Duke to discuss a rapprochement. The Duke fell into the trap of openly snubbing him, which then gives the Baron sufficient legal cover for his subsequent attack.

> ”The fool answered us, Baron!“
>
> ”Whenever did an Atreides refuse the opportunity for a gesture?“ the
> Baron asked. ”Well, what does he say?“
>
> ”He’s most uncouth, Baron. Addresses you as ‘Harkonnen’ — no ‘Sire et
> Cher Cousin,’ no title, nothing.“
>
> ”It’s a good name,“ the Baron growled, and his voice betrayed his
> impatience. ”What does dear Leto say?“
>
> ”He says: ‘Your offer of a meeting is refused. I have ofttimes met
> your treachery and this all men know.’ “
>
> ”And?“ the Baron asked.
>
> ”He says: ‘The art of kanly still has admirers in the Empire.’ He
> signs it: ‘Duke Leto of Arrakis.’ “ Piter began to laugh. ”Of Arrakis!
> Oh, my! This is almost too rich!“
>
> ”Be silent, Piter,“ the Baron said, and the laughter stopped as though
> shut off with a switch. ”Kanly, is it?“ the Baron asked. ”Vendetta,
> heh? And he uses the nice old word so rich in tradition to be sure I
> know he means it.“
>
> **”You made the peace gesture,“ Piter said. ”The forms have been
> obeyed.“**

The Landsraad are fed a story (largely true) about this being a dispute between noble houses.

> “Oh . . . ninety per cent of them are of no concern. But there are always a few . . . Houses Minor and so on, people of ambition who might try a dangerous thing. If one of them should get off Arrakis with an unpleasant story about what happened here, I’d be most displeased. Have you any idea how displeased I’d be?”
>
> Rabban swallowed. “You must take immediate measures to hold a hostage from each House Minor,” the Baron said. **“As far as anyone off Arrakis must learn, this was straightforward House-to-House battle. The Sardaukar had no part in it, you understand? The Duke was offered the usual quarter and exile, but he died in an unfortunate accident before he could accept.** He was about to accept, though. That is the story. And any rumor that there were Sardaukar here, it must be laughed at.”

Answer (score 37):

### [Kanly](https://bookanalysis.com/dune/kanly/)

Houses Atreides and Harkonnen were engaged in a formal feud and the Harkonnen invasion was (except for the Emperor’s involvement) wholly within the rules of the Great Convention.